# Open Elevated "Administrator:" cmd prompt instead of "cmd prompt (Running as Administrator)"

Tags: windows, uac, command-line-interface, runas, user-permissions

If you open a command prompt with a *runas* command, you will see a window that shows

```
(Running as some_user)
```

In the title bar, but if you right click on *cmd.exe* and choose *Run as Administrator* you will get a window that has:

```
Administrator cmd.exe
```

In the title bar.  Oddly enough, these windows exhibit different behavior.

My question is how can I get the **Administrator cmd.exe** command prompt via command line?  Or if it is even possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify which O.S. you are using, but it should be Vista or later, as this is typical [User Account Control](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_Account_Control) behaviour.

Basically, in recent Windows system, even if your user account *is* a member of the Administrators group of the computer, you are still not allowed to perform administrative tasks; if you try to do something actually requiring administrative rights, either the action will fail or a popup window will appear asking you to confirm the action; if you instead only have standard user rights, you will be asked to provide the credentials of a real Administrator account.

If you right-click on something and choose to "Run as Administrator", UAC will ask you for confirmation and then you will be able to effectively bypass it, and the program (not just `cmd.exe`, BTW) will run with full administrative rights. This is especially useful with programs that are *not* compatible with UAC, and tend to silently fail if they require administrative rights and you just double-click on them while UAC is operational.

This of course doesn't have any relevance if UAC is disabled (that can be done via Control Panel), in which case double-clicking the icon or choosing to "Run as Administrator" do exactly the same thing; but the window title will still reflect the "elevated" status of that command prompt.

If you are asking "how can I run a command as Administrator (i.e. elevated) from the command line", AFAIK there is no built-in support for this. It would indeed be nice to have `start /elevated` or `runas /elevated` switches.

Comment: I figured this was the answer, but I was hoping for another :P  I would love that /elevated switch if it were possible.  Thank you for the very well worded explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry for reviving an old question, but in my search for exactly the same thing Google led me here, so maybe this will help someone else looking for this. 
A community-written utility that does exactly what the OP looks for (equivalent of "/elevated" switch for "start" or "runas" command) actually exists:

Original version by John Robbins (C#):
http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2007/03/27/elevate-a-process-at-the-command-line-in-vista.aspx

Rewrite by Johannes Passing (C - no dependency on .Net):
http://jpassing.com/2007/12/08/launch-elevated-processes-from-the-command-line/

Example usage:

```
c:\>elevate cmd.exe
```

Click OK in UAC prompt and you have an administrator command prompt.

Answer (score -1):

to run any program elevated in Windows 7 , hold << LEFT CTRL>> and << LEFT SHIFT>> while launching the program. (ie type cmd and then << Left ctrl>>+<< left shift>>+<< enter>>

Comment: Read the question.  Providing GUI instructions on how to do something, when the question specifically asks how to do it through the CLI is not really an answer.  You're also a year late to this party.